# How to deduce the limit relation $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{cx}-1}{x}=c$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Let $f(x) = e^{cx}$ where $c$ is constant. Show that $f'(0)=c$ and use this to deduce the limit relation $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{cx}-1}{x}=c$$
Proving $f'(0)=c$ is easy but I'm not sure how the limit is proven.

Comment: What is the difference between your question and $f^\prime(0)$. I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the definition of the derivative : $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

Can you go from there ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If you were to apply the *definition* of the derivative to the function $f$ at the point $x = 0$, which limit would you have to calculate?

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that does not rely on differential calculus, but rather relies only on the inequalities for $x<1$

$$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$$

which I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality.

Then, we have

$$c\le \frac{e^{cx}-1}{x}\le \frac{c}{1-cx}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{cx}-1}{x}=c}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may recall that, for any differentiable function $f$ near $a$, one has

> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\to f'(a)
> $$

as $x \to a$.

Answer (score 0):

For  $0 < x < 1$,
$1+x < e^x < \dfrac1{1-x}$.

Therefore,
if $0 < x < \dfrac1{c}$,
$1+cx < e^{cx} < \dfrac1{1-cx}
$
or
$cx < e^{cx}-1 < \dfrac1{1-cx}-1
=\dfrac{cx}{1-cx}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
c 
&< \dfrac{e^{cx}-1}{x}\\
&<\dfrac{c}{1-cx}\\
&=c+\dfrac{c^2x}{1-cx}\\
&<c+2c^2x
\qquad\text{for } cx < \frac12 
\text{ or } x < \frac1{2c}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $x \to 0$,
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{e^{cx}-1}{x}
= c
$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the series expansion:

$$e^{cx} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(cx)^{n}}{n!} $$

Subtract one and dividing by x leaves:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(cx)^{n-1}}{n!} = c + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(cx)^{n-1}}{n!}$$

All terms for n>=2 contain some nonzero power of x and approach zero as x approaches zero.